# How to define DIV stack ordering for responsive narrow displays

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following CSS

```
<DIV class=“container”>
<DIV class=“container”>LEFT</DIV>
<DIV class=“container”>RIGHT</DIV>
</DIV>
```

On wide displays, it prints to screen as below:

```
LEFT   RIGHT
```

And on narrow displays, it prints to screen as below:

```
LEFT
RIGHT
```

What I want however is on narrow screens, for it to print as follows:

```
RIGHT
LEFT
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Where is the code for your "container" class?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is a combination of a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

You'll want to set `display: flex` on the parent, and then set `order: 2` on the first element in conjunction with `order: 1` on the second element, all inside of a media query.

This can be seen in the following, which shows `Left / Right` in the snippet, but `Right / Left` when viewed in a full page.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > div {
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<DIV class='container'>
  <DIV>LEFT</DIV>
  <DIV>RIGHT</DIV>
</DIV>
```

Note that I've removed the `container` class from the inner `<div>` elements, as this would confuse the process, and also fixed up the invalid `“”` quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Are u expecting like this:

Run code snippet, if the screen size is less than 600px its order changes and right div will be printed first and then the left div will be printed.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  /* Standard syntax */
}
.container div {
  width: 100%;
}
.item1 {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
}
.item2 {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item1 {
    -webkit-order: 2;
    /* Safari 6.1+ */
    order: 2;
  }
  .item2 {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    /* Safari 6.1+ */
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">LEFT </div>
  <div class="item2">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```